# Java swing frame preview and actuall size differ

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, netbeans-8

I am writing an application with GUI using Java Swing drag-and-drop in NetBeans IDE. But when I add a component in a small space, it looks correct in the design preview but when I run it, the size is different.

As you can see in the picture, windows 1 and 2 are the same, but when I run the code, the gap on the right side is different (3). Why is that?

I am writing the code in java 8 (1.8.0_05-b13).

[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).  The difference is most easily explained by 'different PLAF'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a consequence of the look-and-feel used in the preview as opposed to the actual execution. Try executing the following at the start of your program to set the LaF to the system one (windows-looking one on Windows):

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
        UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

You'll want to catch and handle `UnsupportedLookAndFeelException`, `ClassNotFoundException`, `InstantiationException`, and `IllegalAccessException`.

Comment: I tried it and it did not work, could be because I implemented the code in the wrong way or place. I will try to recreate the problem with new code post it here as Andrew suggested.

Comment: I found a block of code which could be to problem. Tried posting it but I could not format this reply properly, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: This was indeed the problem. NetBeans implements 'Nimbus' look at the beginning of the main class. When I replaced that with system default (your code), it behaved as I wanted it when I executed the code. When I changed back to what I had before, the problem came back.
[There is a link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) in the comment of the generated code.

Thank you very much!